# How to thread wxPython progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm trying to thread wx.ProgressDialog. I got a Progress threading class

```
class Progress(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        max = 1000000

        dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Progress dialog example",
                               "An informative message",
                               maximum = max,
                               parent=None,
                               style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME
                                | wx.PD_ESTIMATED_TIME
                                | wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME
                                )
        keepGoing = True
        count = 0

        while keepGoing and count < max:
            count += 1
            wx.MilliSleep(250)

            if count >= max / 2:
                (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count, "Half-time!")
            else:
                (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count)
        dlg.Destroy()
```

which gets called when I push a button by

```
class MiPPanel ( wx.Panel ):
    [...]
    def runmiP(self, event):
        thread1 = Progress() 
        thread1.start()
```

When I run thread1.start() I get 100s of warnings of the type `2012-12-01 00:31:19.215 Python[3235:8807] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x11a88f300 of class NSConcreteAttributedString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`
 and the progress bar doesn't show up.

How can I use threading with wxPython to make a progress bar?

Comment: Why do you have a class named `ProgressDialog` that wraps a `ProgressDialog`? That's almost guaranteed to cause confusion to human readers, even if the `wx.` part means the interpreter won't get confused. Also, why is this a class at all, given that it does all its work, including sleeping and destroying the dialog, right there in the `__init__` call?

Comment: Also, `Thread1` doesn't create a `ProgressDialog` at all; it creates a `ProgressFrame`. Are you debugging the right class here?

Comment: oh you're right, it should have been ProgressFrame. This gives me a different error though. And I had the dialogue in the `def run` of Progress, but then I got this error:
2012-12-01 00:28:30.237 Python[3203:a407] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10324b6b0 of class NSConcreteAttributedString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: I assume you're seeing that in the syslogs or the console output. If so, that's not an error, just a warning. It's probably a bug in wx's OS X implementation, but many frameworks have minor bugs like that that don't cause any problems. Unless you're seeing huge or persistent memory leakable, you don't need to fix it. (But, if you're using the current version of the library, you may want to report it so they can fix the bug.)

Comment: the progressbar isn't showing up when I get those warnings

Comment: Well, I can't help you solve question B by looking at the code you posted for question A. I'd suggest you try to gather more information on this new problem, then post a new question about it. If not, at least edit this question to have the right code and description.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple threads accessing wx, which isn't supported. All access to wx should be handled by the same thread that started `wx.App.MainLoop`. You can use `wx.CallAfter` to have commands executed in the correct wx thread, like creating and updating the progress dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All wxPython widgets and manipulation should be in a single thread.  If you want to have a dialog controlled by another thread then you will have to use timers and queues to message the dialog from the other thread.

Another way I understand is supposed to work (I have not tested this) it to create a completely separate wxApp in another thread just for your dialog.  You will have to communicate somehow back to the main thread still.

**Edit:**
Here is a link to more information.  It has some info at the bottom about using wx.CallAfter to update progress of a worker thread.  It also shows how to run a single function in a separate thread without creating a separate class.

[wxPython Threading](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's complaining about argument 4 not being a wxWindow (hence the `argument 4 of type 'wxWindow *'` part of the error).

Looking at your call, argument 4 is passing `parent=self`. So, what is `self`? In other words, what class is the method with this code a part of? Is it something that's a `wx.Window` or subclass of one, or is it something like an `Application` or a `Progress` that isn't?

(Actually, given that you're passing `parent` as a keyword argument, it's just a coincidence that it happened to be in the 4th position in your call to the `wx.ProgressDialog` constructor and also be in the 4th position to the call to the underlying C++ function, which is what's actually complaining. You'd get the same error if you switched `maximum` and `parent`, and I think it would still say `argument 4` instead of `argument 3`.)

To verify this, try taking out the `parent=self` in the call that fails, and it should work, or adding `parent=object()` to the call with just `None` that works, and it should fail.

Of course that doesn't actually *fix* the problem. But to do that, you have to figure out what you wanted the `parent` to be and pass that instead of `self`.

PS, I don't think the problem has anything to do with your threading at all.

Comment: I updated my code, I just don't see why `ProgressFrame(None)` in `def run` wouldn't work but it would work in `runmiP`