# How can I stop a loop with a Toggle Button

Tags: python, wxpython, togglebutton

I´ve made a GUI with a wx.slider and a wx.togglebutton. My goal is to use the slider as a kind of a timeline for a plot and the toggle button as a start/stop button. My ideia is: when I press the toggle button the slider value starts increasing and when I press the toggle button again it stops. I'm using the following code and I can make the slider value increase but once it starts moving I can't stop the loop until it reaches the end of the slider. Is there a way to stop the increase when I press the toggle button again?

```
def m_toggleBtn1OnToggleButton( self, event ):
    value = self.m_toggleBtn1.GetValue()
    if value == True:
        self.m_toggleBtn1.SetLabel("Pause")
        for i in xrange(100):
            if i == 100:
                self.m_slider1.SetValue(100)
            else:
                self.m_slider1.SetValue(i)
                time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        self.m_toggleBtn1.SetLabel("Start")
        slider_value = self.m_slider1.GetValue()
        self.m_slider1.SetValue(slider_value)
```

Thanks for your help.
Kind Regards
Ivo.

Comment: Well, as written you only have one thread of execution, and it's doing the `for i in xrange(100):` loop. It's not going to be a trivial change, because you have to use threading so one thread can run the update loop while the other thread is available to listen for the event. I'm not familiar with wx so not sure what it'll look like, but try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654559/how-to-thread-wxpython-progress-bar?rq=1 and http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks for starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a quick script that I think will do what you want:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.slider_value = 1

        self.slider = wx.Slider(self, value=1, minValue=0, maxValue=100, size=(250, -1),
                                style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider.SetTickFreq(5, 1)
        self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.onScroll)
        self.toggle = wx.ToggleButton(self, label="Start")
        self.toggle.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.onToggle)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onUpdate, self.timer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.slider, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.toggle, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onScroll(self, event):
        """
        Fires when you manually scroll the slider
        """
        value = self.slider.GetValue()
        self.slider_value = value

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onToggle(self, event):
        """
        Start / Stop the slider incrementing
        """
        value = self.toggle.GetValue()
        if value:
            self.toggle.SetLabel("Pause")
            self.timer.Start(1000)
        else:
            self.timer.Stop()
            self.toggle.SetLabel("Start")

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onUpdate(self, event):
        """
        Increment the slider
        """
        self.slider_value += 1
        self.slider.SetValue(self.slider_value)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Slider Test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I would like to thank you for your help. Kind regards. Ivo

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer : http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.Timer.html

Else, you could use a while loop which evaluates a variable that can be changed like that:

```
        while external_variable and i < 100:

        if i == 100:
            self.m_slider1.SetValue(100)
        else:
            self.m_slider1.SetValue(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't aware that I could a Timer that way but after Mike help I finally understand it. Kind regards. Ivo